# RichTextBox latest line

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

let's say I have a RichTextbox that contains the following text:

> Error
>   Warning
>   Info

And let's say I want to change the last word's color to green.
How would I do that? I do have some code to change the color of some text (a replace function), but all I want is to ONLY change the latest line if you know what I mean...

I almost forgot, here is the code that I use to change the word's colors:

```
static void ReplaceText(RichTextBox box, string phrase, Color color)
    {
        box.HideSelection = true;
        int pos = box.SelectionStart;
        string s = box.Text;
        for (int ix = 0; ; )
        {
            int jx = s.IndexOf(phrase, ix, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (jx < 0) break;
            box.SelectionStart = jx;
            box.SelectionLength = phrase.Length;
            box.SelectionColor = color;
            ix = jx + 1;
        }
        box.SelectionStart = pos;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
```

So in other words, how do I ONLY edit the latest line? Thanks!

EDIT: BTW! The colors need to stay there, it's let's say a console output window.

Comment: So wouldn't you split on new line, figure out how many are in the array, get the last one then do your color logic based on that?

Answer (score 4):

This would work for you:

```
public void HighlightLastLine(RichTextBox TextControl, Color HighlightColor)
{
    TextControl.Text = TextControl.Text.Trim();
    TextControl.SelectionStart = 0;
    TextControl.SelectionLength = 0;
    TextControl.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
    string LastLineText = TextControl.Lines[richTextBox1.Lines.Count() - 1];
    int LastLineStartIndex = richTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(LastLineText);
    TextControl.SelectionStart = LastLineStartIndex;
    TextControl.SelectionLength = TextControl.Text.Length - 1;
    TextControl.SelectionColor = HighlightColor;
}
```

Usage:

```
HighlightLastLine(richTextBox1, Color.Indigo);
```

Basically, what we are doing here is doing some clean up first and then selecting the last line of the control using the Lines string array. Then we are getting the last index of that string (incase we have duplicates) and the we just tell the control to start colorizing from the start of the line and go till the end. Finally, we apply the color that is passed in the parameter.

**Edit:**

Adding an overload that will allow custom text highlight and also won't clear the text if passed a false flag in ClearColors parameter.

```
  public void HighlightLastLine(RichTextBox TextControl, string TextToHighlight, Color HighlightColor, bool ClearColors = true)
    {
        TextControl.Text = TextControl.Text.Trim();
        if (ClearColors)
        {
            TextControl.SelectionStart = 0;
            TextControl.SelectionLength = 0;
            TextControl.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
        }
        int LastLineStartIndex = richTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(TextToHighlight);
        if (LastLineStartIndex >= 0)
        {
            TextControl.SelectionStart = LastLineStartIndex;
            TextControl.SelectionLength = TextControl.Text.Length - 1;
            TextControl.SelectionColor = HighlightColor;
            TextControl.SelectionStart = 0;
            TextControl.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
HighlightLastLine(richTextBox1, "Michael Jackson", Color.Indigo, false);
```

This will try to find the last index of Michael Jackson and colorize it. Notice that a false is provided in the last parameter which will allow to retain the existing colors.

Comment: Why use first-letter uppercase argument names... it is very confusing to see C# code written like this.

Comment: Well, it pushes me in the right way for sure :), one more question: how can I do this when I only want to change 1 word in a line, let's say the line contains this: `This is a phone` then I want the word phone to be red, how would I do that oO?  And also keep the colors in the textbox?

Comment: You have to deal with `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` to define where the change of color is going to happen. Experiment with it! It is the only way to learn... Try adding a number to the `SelectionStart` and set `SelectionLength` to a fixed number.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks DelegateX! This worked for me...

```
    public void HighlightLastLine(RichTextBox rtb1, Color fgColour)
    {
        if (rtb1.Text != "")
        {
            // Cleanup leading/trailing whitespace
            rtb1.Text = rtb1.Text.Trim();
            rtb1.SelectionStart = 0;
            rtb1.SelectionLength = 0;
            rtb1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
            // Get index of first char on last line
            string LastLineText = rtb1.Lines[rtb1.Lines.Count() - 1];
            int LastLineStartIndex = rtb1.Text.LastIndexOf(LastLineText);
            // Set selection
            rtb1.SelectionStart = LastLineStartIndex;
            rtb1.SelectionLength = rtb1.Text.Length;
            // Change colour
            rtb1.SelectionColor = fgColour;
        }
    }
```